# jQuery mousewheel event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, mousewheel

Please take a look at this [pen](http://codepen.io/zollex/pen/ZQNvyL)

```
$(function(){
  var i = 0;
  $('.container').bind('mousewheel',function(){
    var rotate = $(this).children("#cube");
    i+=90;
    $('span').text(i);
    rotate.css("transform","rotateX("+i+"deg)")
  })
})
```

The code looks like this, but it better to see that in action

I've bind a `mousewheel` event over the cube,this event triggers a function which increases counter by 90(initially it's set to 0). If you try to do this only once, the counter will be over 4000 or so.

What are possible solutions for this event? Maybe I can make `mousewheel` event softer somehow? Or bind it with another event.

Your help will be appreciated!

Comment: Working fine for me.

Comment: use jquery mouse wheel plugin. https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mousewheel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i` is more than 4000 or so because, mousewheel event will be fired once per each step on mousewheel. So you can use a setTimeout in your event listener to wait for the user to finish his/her scroll and then rotate your image.

```
$(function(){
    var i = 0;
    var timeoutVar;
    $('.container').bind('mousewheel',function(){
        var self = this;
        if (timeoutVar) clearTimeout(timeoutVar); // if this event is fired with in 500ms, previous setTimeout will be cancelled..
        timeoutVar = setTimeout(function () {
            var rotate = $(self).children("#cube");
            i+=90;
            $('span').text(i);
            rotate.css("transform","rotateX("+i+"deg)")     
        }, 500); //adjust this timeout period based on your requirements.
    })
})
```